# AngularJS - Javascript: Is there anything I can do to improve this valid-state function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have this function in an AngularJS service:

```
self.IsValid = function (entity) {
    if (entity == undefined || entity == "undefined")
        return false;

    if (entity == null)
        return false;

    if (entity == "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

A working sample [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/p7iQy44aJ6W9dg16VOBA?p=preview).

Is there anything I can do to improve on this? Or maybe there's a better way altogether?

PS: Resharper says that the `entity == null` check is always false, but that doesn't feel right, I could have passed `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can identify all of the invalid cases, then you can simply list them in an array and then check the entitity against them

```
var invalid = [undefined, "undefined", null, "0000-..."];
var isInArray = invalid.indexOf(entity) >= 0;
return isInArray;
```

This will be easier to maintain than a large compound boolean expression. You could even move this list out into a separate config file, to be shared and injected into your separate services.

Comment: Return  the result directly to shorten the code, `return invalid.indexOf(entity) > -1;`

Comment: In my opinion, that makes it less clear what the function returns, at a glance.

Comment: Accepting this as an answer because it's easily expendable and removes all Resharper warnings.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
self.IsValid = function(entity) {
    return (entity !== "undefined" && entity !== "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") && !!entity;
};
```

1. `entity !== "undefined" && entity !== "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"`: Checks if the value of `entity` variable is not `'undefined'` and `'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'`. If the expression evaluates to `false` the result will be returned.
2. `!!` will cast the value to Boolean. See [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)

[**Updated Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/WYnYdDbiLL8yK58oXevM?p=preview)

Comment: Downvoted. I guess some condition is failing, Can you please add some description, so that the answer can be improved.

Comment: What do you check with `!!entity` that checking `undefined` or `null` doesn't already cover?

Comment: @Spikee Didn't get you, you can read more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript

Comment: I mean, generally speaking, an object is undefined when it's `null`. For Javascript, I think because it's weakly typed, it's decided to have `undefined` as well. But, what other state would there be that you need to check with `!!entity`?

Comment: @Spikee [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). The values here will return `false` when used with double bang `!!` i.e. coerced to boolean. All other values will be [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).